# Set html required if field is required

Tags: django-forms

Before you mark this as duplicate please read.

I know how to set the html required property using the widgets in the form, and also I know how to check in the template if the field is required.

```
<td title="{{field.help_text}}">
   {{field}}
   {% if field.field.required %}
    *
   {% endif %}
</td>
```

The thing is I want the form to be submitted only when the required fields are filled, and as you know the html takes care of that if you set required="required" to those fields.

Is there any way I can do this in my general template so that I don't have to go to every form and set the html property using widgets for every required field ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem mixing django and jquery (as far as I've experienced, django code is 'parsed' first):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("ready",function(){
        {% for field in form.visible_fields  %}
            {% if field.field.required %}
                var input = $("#id_{{field.name}}");
                input.attr("required","required");
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    });
 </script>
```

This `$("#id_{{field.name}}");` works because django forms always (at least in 1.5) adds the id attribute to the inputs in the format "id_fieldname"

If you're using multiple forms the way to get the input is:

```
var input = $("#id_{{form.prefix}}-{{field.name}}");
```

I hope this will be useful for someone.